# How to use '.' in magrittr with numerical formulas

Tags: r, magrittr, wrapr

I am unable to determine how to use (some ?) numerical formulas with `magrittr`. Here is a particular case:

```
library(magrittr)
y = c( complex(1, 1.0,2.0), complex(1, 3.0,4.0))
ymagn = y %>% sqrt(Re(.)**2 + Im(.)**2)
```

Which results in

```
  Error in sqrt(., Re(.)^2 + Im(.)^2) :    2 arguments passed to 'sqrt'
  which requires 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach you can use:

```
ymagn = y %>% {sqrt(Re(.)**2 + Im(.)**2)}
[1] 2.236068 5.000000
```

The reason your version does not work is because by default the `%>%` operator provides the output of the left hand side (LHS) as the first argument of the right hand side (RHS).

Under the default circumstances, if you provide `.` again, *in addition to* providing it as the first argument, the pipe operator will provide the output in place of `.`. As you can read in `` help(`%>%`,"magrittr") ``, the package authors intend you to use this functionality in this type of way:

```
iris %>% subset(., 1:nrow(.) %% 2 == 0)
```

Without the brackets, the code you attempted is evaluated in this way:

```
ymagn = y %>% sqrt(.,Re(.)**2 + Im(.)**2)
```

This explains the error reporting 2 arguments.

---

Using the brackets is called a lambda expression. From `` help(`%>%`,"magrittr") ``:

> #### Using lambda expressions with %>%
>
> Each rhs is essentially a one-expression body of a unary function. Therefore defining lambdas in magrittr is very natural, and as the definitions of regular functions: if more than a single expression is needed one encloses the body in a pair of braces, { rhs }. However, note that within braces there are no "first-argument rule": it will be exactly like writing a unary function where the argument name is "." (the dot).

Comment: I think I understood this as "you need the brackets".  Then your later comment "So your version is really this:" - which does _not_ use brackets -  is confusing. Please clarify

Answer (score 1):

This blog on `magrittr` http://www.win-vector.com/blog/2018/04/magrittr-and-wrapr-pipes-in-r-an-examination/ that also "introduces" `wrapr`  (i.e. it was new to *me* ) - describes the problem clearly:

[image]

Applying that to the original code snippet:

```
library(wrapr)
y = c( complex(1, 1.0,2.0), complex(1, 3.0,4.0))
ymagn = y %.>% sqrt(Re(.)**2 + Im(.)**2)
ymagn

[1] 2.236068 5.000000
```

So `wrapr` is my new friend.

Comment: This is really cool. I think I might use this instead of `{}`.